# Book recommendation on Dedekind's Cuts

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, real-numbers

Is there any book (except Baby Rudin) where **'Dedekind's cuts'** and it's consequences are explained in detailed manner with pictures (in intuitive way)?

**EDIT** Seems that Fikhtengol'ts's "The Fundamental of Mathematical Analysis" (Vol-1) has a little part dedicated to the Dedekind's cuts (which is in a more brain freidnly way).

Comment: I became interested in the construction of a complete ordered field.  My very superficial appraisal was that there are two methods.  One of the methods is supposedly developed in the book "Number Systems and the Foundations of Analysis", Elliott Mendelson, 1973.  I Amazon-purchased this book, only because of its low cost.  I haven't gotten around to attacking it yet.  The other approach is (apparently) Dedekind Cuts.  I just checked: the book that I bought devotes 13 pages (Appendix F) to developing the theory around Dedekind cuts by presenting 13 theorems.

Comment: You can do a lot worse than Dedekind himself. He was a great expositor, his writing is quite modern so it’s not like reading some of the older giants. And the exposition of Dedekind cuts is available from Dover, so it is quite affordable. https://smile.amazon.com/Essays-Theory-Numbers-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486210103

Answer (score 3):

I have been giving this much thought recently. I have been studying Landau's book Foundations of Analysis, which through the beginning of the chapter on cuts, has no pictures. I imagine there are no pictures in the remainder of the book, either.

So it seems that it, alone, is not the book for you. But as a loose interpretation of your request, I offer Landau's book together with the following visualization of a cut that I have used, while reading it.

We start with the (positive) integers, and get progressively fancier. My visualization lives in the first quadrant of the usual plane of coordinate geometry. The primitive integers I represent as a stack of dots growing upwards. (I use the word dot to mean a point of the integer grid within the first quadrant.) In my first picture, you find $1,2,3,4,5,6$.
[image]

Notice I have drawn a ray emanating from the origin and passing through each of the dots $2/1$ and $5/1$. This is the heart of my idea --- to draw such rays in the first quadrant.

Next we get to the (positive) rational numbers. Each has an infinite number of equivalent representations, as even non-mathematicians learn rather early.
[image]

You might get the idea. Let's cheat a bit now, and consider some real numbers, and connect reals to cuts. The way I visualize a non-rational real is as a ray from the origin that is able to travel forever without striking a dot.
[image]

Now, where is a cut? I leave it to you to figure out the cut for a rational, and show the cut for the root of 2. It is simply all rays through any dot, with squared slope less than 2. Let's just show two such rays, in black, to begin.
[image]

Finally what is (the cut corresponding to) the root of two, really? The visualization follows; it is all the black rays. I prefer this to seeing a cut "on the line", because here the equivalence classes of dots (which form the rational numbers) are not erased from the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*Essays on the Theory of Numbers*, a book I used to possess, goes in depth on Dedekind cuts.

It's by Richard Dedekind himself,  is a pretty good read, and I recommend it.

Comment: are there a lot of pictures in the book as requested by the OP?

Comment: @miracle173 to be honest I can't remember.  I don't think there were alot, if there were any.

Comment: I’m sure there aren’t any pictures. The whole point of constructing the real numbers from the integers was to remove the need for geometric intuition.