# Discussion of densely packed rationals around sqrt(2)

Tags: real-analysis

In the first chapter of "Principles of Mathematical Analysis", Mr.Rudin includes a discussion on the set A containing all the positive rationals less than sqrt(2) and the set B containing all the positive rationals greater than sqrt(2). I understand the content, but I'm not sure about the motivation for the discussion :( How does it contribute to the discussion regarding the existence of certain gaps in the rational numbers? Why is showing that there is no largest element of A or smallest element in B important in this context?

[The aforementioned discussion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTxnT.png)

Side note: This is the first time I post anything is stackexchange, so please feel free to criticize me on some conventions I need to follow in this community in the future; thank you :)

Comment: There is no largest member of $A$, but no smallest member of $B$, so something must be "missing."

Comment: Keep reading. Eventually he will use Dedekind sections to define the real numbers. He will also introduce an essential concept which is the least upper bound property of the real numbers.

Comment: If Rudin was saying that, "there is no largest element of A or smallest element in B, and *therefore* there are gaps in the rationals", then he is wrong. To see this, define C to be the set of all positive real numbers whose square is less than $2$, and define D to be the set of all positive real numbers whose square is greater than $2$. Then it is true that  "there is no largest element of C or smallest element in D", however, the real numbers supposedly don't have any gaps... However, I doubt this is what Rudin was saying...

Comment: The very next line of the book says (paraphrasing) "the purpose of the above discussion has been to show that the rational system has certain gaps, despite being dense in itself... the real system fills those gaps" (Possibly he is leaning on the fact that anyone reading this book accepts $\sqrt 2$ as a legitimate number.) @AdamRubinson

Comment: You should read Dedekind's original pamphlet *Continuity and Irrational Numbers*. Rudin's treatment of this topic is boring and unmotivated.

Comment: Also you should try on your own to define real numbers. For example what do you mean by $\sqrt{2}$ (assuming the only numbers you know are rational)?

Answer (score 1):

I think Rudin includes the discussion there, first of all, to provide an example of a very typical analysis activity, the creation and manipulation of inequalities. The motivation for the discussion is the actual *definition of the real number system*, which many students never see. (It does appear in the Chapter 1 Appendix of the 3rd Edition of Rudin.)
As you know, the root of $2$ is irrational and real. One possible definition of this number is

> a non-trivial binary partition of all rational numbers, the first class $A$ of which contains every $r>0: r^2 < 2$ and all non-positive rationals, while the second class $B$ contains every $r>0: r^2 > 2.$

Again, the root of $2$ is not rational; it is missing from *the rational number system*. But the text above is a way of describing this "certain gap" indirectly, using only concepts from the given rational number system.

If you should choose to make a study of one of the schemes for defining the real number system, you might encounter the question of whether there is, or is not, a largest element of the lower class $A$. It has technical importance when we go to show that you can do *arithmetic* with these non-trivial binary partitions of all rational numbers. For instance what does it really mean to find $\sqrt 3 - \sqrt2$ with such a definition of "numbers"?

Also important is an introduction to the notions of limit and convergence. If you are picturing a bounded-above set $A$ with no largest element, it seems you can travel indefinitely upwards (or rightwards if you prefer). But towards what destination are we traveling, with this sequence?

**Edit:** You may also find these pictures interesting: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4123656/688046